# Building two executables in one project

Tags: cocoa, xcode, build

I've a project that must produce two executables: the main application and an executable that is called by a separate process.

I've created the second file in Xcode and added a second target of type Cocoa Shell Tool. I can now build the second executable but when I try to build my project normally I get an error saying there's two executables present:

```
ld: duplicate symbol _main in <path>/SecondExecutable.o and <path>/main.o
```

(`<path>` was added by me to protect the innocent and their intelectual property).

How can I configure Xcode to build both at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your app source file is only in the app target, and the tool source file is only in the tool target.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to select each file, choose Get Info, and look at the Targets tab: each main should only have one target checked.